# Crazy Query need some feedback

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
        var query =context.Categories.Include("ChildHierarchy")
             .Where(c =>
                 context.CategoryHierarchy.Where(ch => ch.ParentCategoryID == ch.ParentCategoryID)
                 .Select(ch => ch.ChildCategoryID).Contains(c.CategoryID));
```

Questions:

1. I need to include some data from another Navigation Propery (".Include("otherprop")")
2. Is it possible to do a select new after all of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title to your question intrigued me with the words "Crazy Query", and yes, you're right, it is a bit crazy.

You have a `.Where(...)` clause with the following predicate:

```
ch => ch.ParentCategoryID == ch.ParentCategoryID
```

Now that's going to always be true. So I guess that you're trying to do something else. I'll have a crack at what that might be at the end of my answer.

I then did some cleaning up of your query to get a better idea of what you're doing. This is what it now looks like:

```
var query =
    context
        .Categories
        .Where(c => context
            .CategoryHierarchy
            .Select(ch => ch.ChildCategoryID)
            .Contains(c.CategoryID));
```

So rather than use nested queries I would suggest something like this might be better in terms of readability and possibly performance:

```
var query =
    from c in context.Categories
    join h in context.CategoryHierarchy
        on c.CategoryID equals h.ChildCategoryID into ghs
    where ghs.Any()
    select c;
```

This gives the same results as your query so hopefully this is helpful.

I do get the impression that you're trying to do a query where you want to return each Category along with any child categories it may have. If that's the case here are the queries you need:

```
var lookup =
    (from c in context.Categories
     join h in context.CategoryHierarchy
         on c.CategoryID equals h.ChildCategoryID
     select new { ParentCategoryID = h.ParentCategoryID, Category = c, }
    ).ToLookup(x => x.ParentCategoryID, x => x.Category);

var query =
    from c in context.Categories
    select new { Category = c, Children = lookup[c.CategoryID], };
```

The `lookup` query first makes a join on categories and the category hierarchies to return all children categories and their associated `ParentCategoryID` and then it creates a lookup from `ParentCategoryID` to a list of associated `Category` children.

The query now just has to select all categories and perform a lookup on the `CategoryID` to get the children.

The advantage of using the `.ToLookup(...)` approach is that it easily allows you to include categories that don't have children. Unlike using a `Dictionary<,>` the lookup does not throw an exception when you use a key that it hasn't got a value for - instead it returns an empty list.

Now, you can add back in the `.Include(...)` calls too.

```
var lookup =
    (from c in context.Categories
        .Include("ChildHierarchy")
        .Include("otherprop")
     join h in context.CategoryHierarchy
        on c.CategoryID equals h.ChildCategoryID
     select new { ParentCategoryID = h.ParentCategoryID, Category = c, }
    ).ToLookup(x => x.ParentCategoryID, x => x.Category);

var query =
    from c in context.Categories
        .Include("ChildHierarchy")
        .Include("otherprop")
    select new { Category = c, Children = lookup[c.CategoryID], };
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Awesome and thanks much. I will go and test this out in LinqPad and get back with you. It looks like it will do the trick and has taught me some things in the process...

Comment: I finally got to actually testing all of this. Sorry for the delay and response. This does not seem to be supported in linq-entities. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: @Anoddperson - Try adding a `.ToArray()` after the `context.Categories.Include(...)` in the final query. That'll bring the categories into memory in a single query and that will work fine with the look up. I assume that you have a relatively small number of categories - ie, not millions - so this would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Then add it - `context.Categories.Include("ChildHierarchy").Include("OtherCollection");`

2) Absolutely, yes

```
var query = context.Categories
            .Include("ChildHierarchy")
            .Include("OtherProp")
            .Where(c => context.CategoryHierarchy.Where(ch => ch.ParentCategoryID == ch.ParentCategoryID)
                .Select(ch => ch.ChildCategoryID).Contains(c.CategoryID))
            .Select(c => new { c.A, c.B, c.etc });
```